# can't use variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

My main Makefile call config.mk

```
include $(TOPDIR)/config.mk
```

then config.mk include some sentences like this:

```
ifdef CPU
sinclude $(TOPDIR)/cpu/$(CPU)/config.mk
endif

ifdef SOC
sinclude $(TOPDIR)/cpu/$(CPU)/$(SOC)/config.mk
endif
```

I have prepared these two tree and necessary config.mks. But for "SOC", whose value is "versatile", there is a problem. If I put "versatile" directly here, it could find the file and everything is fine; but when I use $(SOC), il will meet an error, and say

```
/../../../cpu/arm926ejs/versatile: is a folder, stop
```

Anyone know what the problem is ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you gave the exact error message?  What version of make are you using?  That error doesn't look like anything GNU make would print.

Anyway, I'll bet the problem is that your assignment of the `SOC` variable has trailing whitespace.  According to the POSIX definition of `make`, leading whitespace before a variable value is removed, but trailing whitespace is *preserved*.  That means, for example, if you write your makefile like this:

```
SOC = versatile # this is the versatile SOC
```

then make will remove the comment, but *keep the space*, so the value will be '`versatile`' (space at the end).  This means when the value is expanded in the `sinclude` line you get:

```
sinclude $(TOPDIR)/cpu/$(CPU)/versatile /config.mk
```

which make interprets as trying to include two different values, the first of which is a directory.

Even if you don't have a comment there, any trailing whitespace will be preserved.  When editing makefiles you should try to put your editor into a mode where it flags trailing whitespace, or even better removes it automatically.  GNU Emacs, for example, can do this.

Comment: that's exactly the error you bet! I've solved my problem easily. Thank you very much!!